# How can I reduceByKey count occurances of column value in column list?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have an RDD userMovies

```
 userID, movieID, list of movieIDs
[(69120, (296, [296, 356, 2858, 608, 588, 1580, 597, 153, 4306, 587]))],...
```

I wish to count the amount of times the 2nd column value is in the list in the 3rd column.

```
userMovies.reduceByKey(lambda v : 1 if v[1][0] in v[1][1] else 0).take(1)
```

I tried to have an RDD by adding 1 or 0 through a reduceByKey and after that sum the total RDD value, as in summing up all the 1s. But the reduceByKey returns the same RDD back and doesn't give a 1 or 0.

EDIT:

```
userMovies.map(lambda tup: (tup[0], (tup[1][0], 1 if tup[1][0] in tup[1][1] else 0))).reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a[1][1]+b[1][1]).take(2)
```

RETURNS

```
[(43450, (84152, 0)), (60830, (345, 0))]
```

I need only one row-column [(totalsum)] not per key

Comment: I would just use a [Counter()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count all the element in the list and then access the one you are interested in.

Comment: Could you show an example? Also why count the list, I need the count the amount of times the 2nd column shows up in the list and sum for each key. Per key the result is either 0 or 1. In the end the full RDD counted up should give the amount of occurances.

Comment: "I wish to count the amount of times the 2nd column value is in the list in the 3rd column." This means you want to count the occurrences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you map your RDD to the second tuple element, you should be able to reduce by key:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(69120, (296, \
        [296, 356, 2858, 608, 588, 1580, 597, 153, 4306, 587]))])

rdd = rdd.map(lambda tup: (tup[0], (tup[1][0], 1 if tup[1][0] in tup[1][1] else 0)))
```

This keeps the same tuple structure, but replaces the movie list with the number of occurences of movie ID in it:

```
dd.collect()
```

That code outputs:

```
[(69120, (296, 1))]
```

That is `(userID, (movieID, 1 if found else 0))`

If you need to compute the total number of views per movie (for all users):

```
rdd.map(lambda l: l[1])\
   .reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)\
   .collect()
```

With this collection, the result will be similar for the single movie:

```
[(296, 1)]
```

Comment: Will the end result return just the total amount or the keys aswell?

Comment: I have the result [(26970, 0]) does this mean the amount of occurances is 26970 or is that userID?

Comment: I just want to count the 1s of all keys that have the 1s. So total amount of occurances.

Comment: @JayLincon Edited. All you needed to do was map, counting second value in third...

Comment: How can i get the total sum? My end goal is  RDD with one column row [(totalsum)]

Comment: total sum of what? Sum of views per movie (this is what I had before the edit)? What's there right now is sum of views per user per movie.

Comment: Now you have examples of both (count of views for the movie per user, and count of views per movie for all users)

Comment: I need the total times the 2nd column  value is in the list. Each user can get a 1 or 0. In the end i count up all the 1s and get a total amount

Comment: It's not about the views per movie it's only about how many times the occurance was right. Each user has a true or false. 1 or 0. In the end I count up all the True occurances. As in the 1s

Comment: The end result after getting the 1s or 0s for each key and then counting up all the 1s:  [(totalsum)]

Comment: If you just want to count each time movieID is found in list, then `.map(lambda tup: (tup[0], (tup[1][0], 1 if tup[1][0] in tup[1][1] else 0)))` is what you're looking for

Comment: Yes, I'm getting int is not iterable after calling reduceByKey on that. Dont know why

Comment: The version in this answer won't (doesn't in fact) cause that error because it's mapping to the inner tuple.

Comment: Alright I will retry on this version, but will the reduceByKey result in only 1 row? That's what I need

Comment: I have edited the post and there you can see it doesnt return the full sum it just goes by user

Comment: Did you notice this in my answer: `rdd.map(lambda l: l[1])\
   .reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)\
   .collect()`? This `rdd` is the same one created by the preceding statement. Your updated question does a `reduceByKey` done incorrectly. If you just use all the lines of code in this answer, it will give you the expected results.

Comment: I'm sorry all I had to do was sum() to get what I need

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using just Counter() ?

```
from collections import Counter

a = [(69120, (296, [296, 356, 2858, 608, 588, 1580, 597, 153, 4306, 587]))]
k = a[0][1][0]
i = a[0][1][1]
r = Counter(i)[k] #occurrences of k in i also i.count(k) would be ok.

>>> print(k, r)
296 1
```